# How to put calculated data into INSERT query in a Spark.Sql code

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I was trying to insert 4 data into a table:
 and for insertion I'm using below code-

```
spark.sql("INSERT INTO countDirectorySize VALUES (`" +str(root) + "`, `" +str(dirSize) + "`, `" +str(today1) + "`, `" +str(today2)+ "`)")
```

Let me put the entire code here for better understanding-

```
import os
from datetime import date
size=0
root = "/dbfs/mnt/datalake/.../"
today1 = date.today()
dirSize = size/(1024*1024)
today2 = date.today()

spark.sql("INSERT INTO countDirectorySize VALUES (`" +str(root) + "`, `" +str(dirSize) + "`, `" +str(today1) + "`, `" +str(today2)+ "`)")
```

And this code gives error while inserting. What am I doing wrong.

Error:

```
cannot resolve '`/dbfs/mnt/datalake/.../`' given input columns: []; line 1 pos 39;\n'InsertIntoTable 'UnresolvedRelation `countDirectorySize`, false, false\n+- 'UnresolvedInlineTable [col1, col2, col3, col4], [List('/dbfs/mnt/datalake/.../, '`9.256933212280273`, '2020-06-01, '2020-06-01)]\n"
```

Comment: can you add the error please?

Comment: @M.Alexandru Hey, Updated the question with error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing But changing the script and arranging it worked smoothly and inserted data-

Arrangement technique:   `('"__"')`

Its-

```
spark.sql("INSERT INTO countDirectorySize VALUES ('"+str(root)+"','"+str(dirSize)+"','"+str(today1)+"','"+str(today2)+"')")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using plain insert statement, I would recommended to build a dataframe and register it as a table.

Here is what I did with your code:

```
import os
from datetime import date    
data = []    
size=0
root = "/Users/hbohra/Desktop/"
today1 = date.today()
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        size += os.path.getsize(os.path.join(path, name))
        dirSize = size/(1024*1024)
today2 = date.today()
data.append((root, dirSize, today1, today2))    
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=['dir_name', 'dir_size', 'created_date', 'modified_date'])
df.registerTempTable('countDirectorySize')

#spark.sql("INSERT INTO countDirectorySize VALUES (`" +str(root) + "`, `" +str(dirSize) + "`, `" +str(today1) + "`, `" +str(today2)+ "`)")

df2 = spark.sql('select * from countDirectorySize')
```

Output:

```
>>> df2.show()
+--------------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+
|            dir_name|         dir_size|created_date|modified_date|
+--------------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+
|/Users/hbohra/Des...|428.3244695663452|  2020-06-01|   2020-06-01|
+--------------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+

>>>
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, But I need a permanent table where I can keep storing all data everytime I run this program.

Comment: You can create a permanent table manually one time, and execute either "insert into permanent_table select * from temp table" or Merge/Upsert at the end of above program.